# Can I have a view that merges my Program Files (x86) and Program Files?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Sometimes I need to browse to find an installed application, but I often forgot whether they are installed in "Program Files (x86)" or "Program Files". Is there a trick where I can see the merged view of these two folders in a standard "browse file" dialog?

Answer (score 4):

You could create a "Program Files" library and add both folders to it.